# JavaScript loaded page animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, animation

I want to design a page that displays my name. When the site starts working, the page takes the entire width and length, but when 15 seconds pass, I want it to be placed in another place to be replaced by another page, and so on

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "explain how u are trying to solve your problem and what difficulties you encounter"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution from what I understand of your question:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
      document.getElementById('content').style.display="none";
      var state = document.readyState
      if (state == 'complete') {
          setTimeout(function(){
             document.getElementById('load').classList.remove("center");
               document.getElementById('content').style.display="block";
          },1500);
      }
    }
```

```css
  .center{
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
        display:flex; 
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        z-index:9999;
    }
```

```html
<div id="load" class="center">Your name</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
```